# How can I use node_load() with a module created page that requires an argument?

Tags: 6

I would like to load the contents of a page like how node_load() works, although what I am trying to load isn't a node but a page created using a module. The entry in hook_menu uses an argument which needs to be passed in the URL. This is for a popup (jquery overlay) that I want to reuse where the code is already done for the standalone version.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: What do you think about a view? How do you want to pass the argument?

Comment: I'm not sure, would a view work? I've never looked into views, I'll have to have a read.

Comment: Not using Views with Drupal is like eating with your bare hands : it'll work, but will be much more difficult than using a fork, and you'll get your hands dirty in the process.

Comment: After some reading and testing and watching of videos I am left wondering if Views can accomplish this task? How can I use Views to view a page created by a module?

Comment: As far as I recall, the Views module doesn't return the page created by another module as output; its purpose is just to return a page listing some entities (nodes, users, taxonomy terms) that match the criteria set for the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

The code executed from Drupal, in index.php, contains the following code.

```
$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
      drupal_site_offline();
      break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
  print theme('page', $return);
}
```

[menu_execute_active_handler()](http://menu_execute_active_handler) accepts an argument: the path being shown. If that argument is not passed to the function, then [menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/6), the function called by `menu_execute_active_handler()` uses the content of `$_GET['q']`.
In your case, you would pass to the path you are interested to. Your function should use code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_get_page($path = NULL) {
  $return = menu_execute_active_handler($path);

  // Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
  if (is_int($return)) {
    return $return;
  }

  if (isset($return)) {
    return theme('page', $return);
  }

  return −1;
}
```

The calling function would need to check the returned value: If it is a string, then it the what returned from `theme('page')`; if it −1, then the menu callback didn't return any value (but could have printed the page content; if it is an integer different than −1, then it's a Drupal error code, i.e. the one reporting the site is off-line, the user is trying to access a page without to have any permission, or the user is trying to access a non existing page.

The only "problem" with this code is that sometimes a menu callback doesn't return any content, but it prints the content directly; this is normally done for content that doesn't need to appear together the rest of the page output Drupal normally adds (e.g. the content for the blocks associated to a page), such as when a module returns XML content that should not mixed up with the HTML output generated from Drupal.
In this case, the function should intercept the output directly printed, with [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php).

```
function mymodule_get_page($path = NULL) {
  ob_start();
  $return = menu_execute_active_handler($path);
  $output = ob_get_flush();

  // Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
  if (is_int($return)) {
    return $return;
  }

  if (isset($return)) {
    return theme('page', $return);
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: How should I be calling this function?

Comment: You can call it from the page callback, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad way of doing this and certain things will not work (such as inline javascript). I haven't been able to find 'the proper way' of doing this so what I did was create a page with PHP input and passed the view function for the page I wanted to `echo()`. I could then use `node_load()` and `node_view()` to grab the content for display. I wouldn't recommend this method but it's the only one I've found to solve the problem so far. More suggestions welcomed!